# Apollo readFragment and dataIdFromObject

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

I've configured `ApolloClient` like this:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4000',
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
        dataIdFromObject: obj => obj.id as string,
        addTypename: false
    })
});
```

Now I want to use `apolloClient.readFragment` to read something from the cache, however it keeps returning an empty object `{}` even though it looks like it's in the cache.

```
            console.log('readFragment',optimisticUpdate)
            const {id,fragment,data} = optimisticUpdate
            rollback = apolloClient.readFragment({id,fragment},true)
            console.log("ROLLBACK",rollback)
            apolloClient.writeFragment(optimisticUpdate)
```

[image]

If I remove the `dataIdFromObject` and `addTypename` options from `InMemoryCache` and change the `id` to include the typename then it seems to work, but I don't see why I should have to do that because all my IDs are guaranteed to be unique.